# Crash while casting the result of JSONObjectWithData to Dictionary<String,Any>

Tags: ios, swift

The Application crashes while parsing JSON result to `<String,Any>` it does not enters the catch block:

```
        do
        {
            result = try NSJSONSerialization.JSONObjectWithData(data, options: NSJSONReadingOptions.AllowFragments) as! Dictionary<String,Any>
        }
        catch let error1 as NSError
        {
            result = nil
            print(error1)
        }
```

While if I casted the JSON result to `<String,AnyObject>` it works fine:

```
        do
        {
            result = try NSJSONSerialization.JSONObjectWithData(data, options: NSJSONReadingOptions.AllowFragments) as! Dictionary<String,AnyObject>
        }
        catch let error1 as NSError
        {
            result = nil
            print(error1)
        }
```

Is not the `<Any>` protocol accepts both the primitive types and the object types , then why it's failing ?

Answer (score 2):

The reason you are crashing is the forced cast you are making. The do / catch construct in Swift doesn't work like exceptions in other languages, where any error will be caught in the catch block. In your case

```
NSJSONSerialization.JSONObjectWithData(data, options: NSJSONReadingOptions.AllowFragments)
```

can throw an error, and the catch block will be called if an error is thrown. In contrast the forced cast to Dictionary does not throw an error if it fails. It would be far better to wrap the cast in an if let like so:

```
do
{
    let temp = try NSJSONSerialization.JSONObjectWithData(data, options: NSJSONReadingOptions.AllowFragments) 

    if let result = temp as? Dictionary<String,AnyObject> {
        // Do something with the result
    }
    else {
        // cast failed handle it gracefully
    }
}
catch let error1 as NSError
{
    result = nil
    print(error1)
 }
```

Now as to why the cast to "String, AnyObject" works while "String, Any" fails, I suspect it has to do with the fact that originally, it is an NSDictionary being returned from your JSON call. Those are bridged to Swift Dictionaries as "String, AnyObject". Now, what you are trying to do should technically work, and I consider it a bug that it doesn't. You might consider filing a radar for this behavior. In the meantime, it would also be advisable to avoid force casting as much as possible.

Answer (score 1):

Don't use `Any`.

`AnyObject` covers all types JSON supports.